# Math Environments / comment lines

Tags: formatting

I can not cope with such formatting (as pictured). 
[image]

I do not know how to divide the comment lines. Thank you for the tip. It would be wonderful if it was a solution that works for mathjax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put the comments in parboxes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{x^2-1}{1-x} &= \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{(x-1)(x+1)}{-(x-1)} &\quad& 
       \parbox{160pt}{\raggedright Factoring the numerator and factoring $-1$ from the denominator.} \\
                                &= \lim_{x\to1}\frac{x+1}{-1}=-2, && 
       \parbox{100pt}{\raggedright Simplifying and subsituting $x=1$.} 
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image: comments]

Comment: I prefer to type `&\quad&` in all rows, so there's no assumption on their lengths.

Comment: @egreg --- Is there a potential pitfall to just having `&&` in the second row?

Comment: If you edit the text and the second part happens to be wider than the first one…

Comment: Thank you very much Ian and egreg, exactly what I needed. I depend on it to be able to also do so on the website (with mathjax), but it probably will not succeed.